# editing the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a `while` loop in my video poker java game. I'm using this loop to ask the player whether they want to keep the current cards in their hand. There's another `while` loop inside the first one that asks the player to enter a valid answer in case their entered anything other than "yes" or "no." For some reason, it skips every other card in the hand. For instance, it will say, "Do you want to keep card number 1?" Then I press yes/no, and it asks next, "Do you want to keep card number 3?" instead of number 2. Can you help me figure out why this is happening, please?

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 6)
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to keep the card number " + i + "?");
    System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
    String answer = input.next();
        while((!answer.equals("yes")) && (!answer.equals("no")))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid answer");
            answer = input.next();
        }

        if (answer.equals("yes"))
        {
            toKeep.add(p.getHand().get(i-1));
            i++;
        }
        else if (answer.equals("no"));
        {
            i++;
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
else if (answer.equals("no"));
{
     i++;
}
```

If the answer equals `no` it ends the statement (semicolon). Then it executes the block `i++`, no matter what the answer was.

Where you should have:

```
else if (answer.equals("no"))
{
     i++;
}
```

If the answer equals `no` it executes block `i++`

Comment: This is something that you can easily avoid using an IDE and reading it's warnings/errors. Also, this `else if` block could be avoided, i++ should be at the end of while loop, and removed elsewhere.

Comment: @maremp Exactly, I edited the code format in the question using eclipse and instantly saw where the problem was.

Comment: Where can I find a good tutorial on how to use eclipse with java? I'm new to all this...

Comment: @user3505003 A quick google search gets me [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html), but you should be able to find a lot of other tutorials quite easily. You have other options apart from eclipse, like NetBeans or IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks,I'll try to find something that works well. I've been trying to learn how to use an IDE, but my class is so fast paced, I barely get enough time to finish assignments.

Answer (score 0):

First you added a semicolon at the end of the else if condition,

Second you should put an `input.nextLine()` before closing the while loop.

Here's the final code:

```
while (i < 6)
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to keep the card number " + i + "?");
    System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
    String answer = input.next();
        while((!answer.equals("yes")) && (!answer.equals("no")))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid answer");
            answer = input.next();
        }

        if (answer.equals("yes"))
        {
            toKeep.add(p.getHand().get(i-1));
            i++;
        }
        else if (answer.equals("no"))
        {
            i++;
        }
        input.nextLine(); // JUNK
}
```